# Problems with using popToViewController to go back to a specific view controller going to black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am using doing something basic like this to push to a view.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.navigationController.storyboard;

MenuViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Some places I can simply use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But in a few places I want to pop to a specific view controller. What I have tried is:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.navigationController.storyboard;

RecordMenuViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"recordMenuViewController"];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

But it just goes to a black screen like the view isn't in the stack or something. What am I missing here?

Comment: [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"recordMenuViewController"] - create new instance of RecordMenuViewController. [self.navigationController popToViewController:... animated:YES]; - can return only to specific instance of a ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pop to a specific view controller using the navigation stack, do the following:

```
NSArray* vcs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController* target = [vcs objectAtIndex:([vcs count] - 1) - numVCsToGoBack];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:target];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pop to specific view controller in the stack use following code:

(here consider you have to pop to `MyViewController` Class)

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
     if ([controller isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
     {
       [navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
       break;
     }
 }
```